# Sign in with Google disabled for this app in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

we have implemented google drive API in our app. previously it's working perfectly. but now from some times, it's not working it's given me some error like "**This app is not verified**". so we have to verify our application from the OAuth consent screen. and it's verified successfully. now I got an error like "**Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app**".  it works perfectly for the old user. but when I log in with a new user it's given me this error.

Is there any user limit like 100 users? Because we found 100 user cap limits on the OAuth consent screen. please refer below screenshot and get me out of this problem please help.

[image]

Comment: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en

Comment: Hello @Paulw, I have already verified my application the status Is also changed to Verified. What should I do please help

Comment: Use firebase Auth

Comment: When did you verify?  The support page says you may have to wait up to a day for the cap to reset

Comment: @A.Amini, but I must use google authentication. what should i do?

Comment: Firebase includes Google auth, and ist from google.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth

Comment: Hello @Paulw11, below I have sent you the screenshot link of my verified app please let me know what is wrong in it,
https://ibb.co/6tgM9xf

Comment: It says that your app is requesting OAuth scopes that have not been approved. Re-check the approval process and ensure that all,of the scopes you are requesting have been verified.

Comment: @Paulw11, please refer below screenshot which doesn't have any scope that is sensitive and restricted,
https://ibb.co/Tmh6WBQ

Comment: Make sure that you aren't requesting different scopes in your app code than you have requested in the consent screen

Comment: Hello @Paulw11, Thank you very much. It's working because the scope we have used is different from the consent screen. and now we have changed the scope the same as the consent screen. 
Really very glad that you sorting out our problem.
Thank you very much